# How to make the channel entries tag return the same entry more than once?

Tags: channel-entries

I am passing a pipe-delimited list of entry ids into a standard channel entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    entry_id="149|453|321|149"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="4"}

        {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I only get 3 results returned, with the second 149 ignored. There seems to be some filter stripping it out. I have gone through the docs but I have not found any parameter along the lines of allow_duplicates="".

How can I make the channel entries tag return the same entry twice if I explicitly request it by entry id?

Comment: You could always use more than one channel:entries loop right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The channel:entries tag will always return unique/distinct entries. No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

A more advanced approach, but your best bet might be to use [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) - stash that entry in your logic template, then use it more than once if needed in the wrapper template. Since you're trying to return a duplicate entry, you may need to also stash the entry ID or something so you can use it in your wrapper template to target it distinctly.  For a primer on template partials using Stash, have a look at [Adrienne Travis' article on eeinsider](http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash/).

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the values you're using to create the pipe-delimited list and call `exp:channel:entries` for each hit.

I tried getting all rows in SQL, so you could use `exp:query` and pass each `entry_id` into an embed, but SQL only returns the distinct rows as well, seemingly no matter what you throw at it.

```
Select entry_id from exp_channel_titles t where entry_id in (1, 2, 3, 1)
```

If you do pull each entry individually in a loop, consider making it a plugin or using `exp:query` to optimize things.